# Nest can't resolve dependencies .Please make sure that the argument ImageFileS ervice at index [1] is available in the ItemModule context

Tags: javascript, node.js, dependency-injection, nestjs

I get this error

ERROR [ExceptionHandler] Nest can't resolve dependencies of the ItemController (ItemService, ?). Please make sure that the argument ImageFileS
service at index [1] is available in the ItemModule context.

I have this code

ImageFileModule :

```
@Module({
  imports: [TypeOrmModule.forFeature([ImageFile]), ConfigModule, ItemModule],
  controllers: [ImageFileController],
  providers: [ImageFileService],
  exports: [ImageFileService],
})
export class ImageFileModule {}
```

ItemModule :

```
@Module({
  imports: [TypeOrmModule.forFeature([Item])],
  controllers: [ItemController],
  providers: [ItemService],
  exports: [ItemService],
})
export class ItemModule {}
```

Service That I am trying to use:

```
@Injectable()
export class ImageFileService {
  constructor(
    @InjectRepository(ImageFile)
    private readonly imageFileRepository: Repository<ImageFile>,
    private readonly configService: ConfigService,
    private readonly itemService: ItemService,
  ) {}
```

Comment: Please show us the`ItemService` constructor

Comment: Most likely you just need to add `ImageFileModule` to the `imports` of the `ItemModule`